# angular input with regex

Tags: regex, angular

I have couple of inputs in Angular form. 
I use `FormGroup`, `FormControl`, `FormBuilder`, the following `Validators`:

```
 this.addUserFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
       lastName: ['',[
         Validators.required,
         Validators.pattern(InputPatterns.AlphabeticSpace),
         Validators.minLength(VALIDATION.LAST_NAME_MIN_LENGTH),
         Validators.maxLength(VALIDATION.LAST_NAME_MAX_LENGTH)
       ]]});
```

and this pattern:

```
 AlphabeticSpace = '/^[a-zA-Z\-\ \']*$/',
```

I have a bug that when I enter some characters like `!$#&` there is no validation error, but when I enter other like `<>,:+_` error message appear.

How can I hack that?

Comment: can you add your code in stackblitz.com

Comment: space doesn't need to be escaped try `/^[a-zA-Z\- ']*$/`